# Java String manipulation (A/B)+C

Tags: java, string

is there any java library in the wild which can "calculate" string:

```
(aaa/bbb/ccc)+ddd
```

into

```
aaa ddd, bbb ddd, ccc ddd
```

and can maybe "solve" nested:

```
(a+(b/c))/((d/e)+f)
```

to

```
a b, a c, d f, e f
```

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a homework question in school...

Comment: Are you looking for a math parser? Google for c#/java math parser and you will find enough resources. Otherwise there is much logic stuff to do, i dont know any library which does this kind of string fiddling - mostly because it does not make sense (at least for me). Maybe you want to clarify what exactly your trying to do.

Comment: @sdavids any reasons to think so? it could be pretty production task.

Comment: @Andrey In my old freshman level intro classes they usually gave us silly String manipulation problems like this - and school has only been in for about 3 weeks - which means students would only be at the low level string manipulation stage.

Comment: @sdavids the task might be silly because its string manipulation par excellance, but the core task (parsing math expressions) is a) quite hard and b) a good excercise for compiler guys.

Comment: @sdavids It sure look like homework assignement, but I gave a simple example out of many patterns I must "solve". The task is to convert one format into another and this is just one step. The process must be repeatable and yes, it is for production. There are operators like + (plus), but it does not mean adding one thing to another and there is / (slash), but it does not mean dividing. And there are others - that is why I was looking for a "string math" expression library before reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of any off hand, but I would go ahead and just write the code off hand.  Parse the file, find (), Split strings by /, at the end add all / strings with the + string, and it should work out.

Comment: sounds easy peasy but wont work for sure, there are many rules you have to care about and if hes trying to solve equations with strings its quite recursive, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try a parser generator for Java such as [Jack](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1996/jw-12-jack.html) or [one](http://catalog.compilertools.net/java.html) of the [others](http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/96-06-045).  Parsers are a great tool in a programmer's repertoire, and those tools make them fairly easy.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to solve a equation. Then you can do this:

1. Use regex to split the equation or split the string to create an array of individual chars.
2. Use a [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) in Java to construct the List, follow BODMAS: search, solve and remove.

Example: 2-3+1

Regex gives: [2, -, 3, +, 1]

Insert it into a LinkedList and first search for (), then +..etc (follow BODMAS). So when + is encountered, do: -3+1, remove + and 1. Replace 3 with the sum (2).

Comment: regexps sounds like a bad idea when parenthesis are involved... (The expressions to parse are not regular!)

Comment: Id say so, too. Afaik you cant build parser like that with regexp, the language is just too limited (has something to do with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)

Comment: No, I am not trying to do math.

Answer (score 0):

I know a open source math parser from [mycsharp.de](http://www.mycsharp.de/wbb2/thread.php?threadid=71995&hilight=math+expression+parse) which got quite good feedback, its C# but might be a good example how to go (and easy to convert). Sadly, its not only C# but german.

But there are many math parser out there, just google "math expression parser" or something like that. Have a look at [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29), too!